# NSCoreData: delegate methods not called on save for particular entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have the following three methods for you to look at:

https://gist.github.com/emilevictor/6e01e9c30ce38e9e8a3f

The first method, "actionsheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:" creates either a TreatmentLaser, a TreatmentPASI or a TreatmentSurgery. When these entities are saved, the delegate (method 3) is always called. This is done without fail.

The second method, "onClickNewConsultation:", does the same thing - this time with two entities, Consult and ClinicalExam. They are related to each other. The first time the VC is loaded and this method is called by a button, the delegate method is called. Every time from then on however, it is not. Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case?

Edit:

Code added here in case the gist is deleted:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSInteger adjustedIndex = 0;

    if (!_laserEnabled) {
        adjustedIndex++;
        if (!_pasiEnabled)
            adjustedIndex++;
    }
    else if (!_pasiEnabled && buttonIndex > 0) {
        adjustedIndex++;
    }

    //    if (!_laserEnabled && adjustedIndex > 2)
    //        adjustedIndex++;
    //    }

    switch (buttonIndex + adjustedIndex) {
        case 0:
        {
            TreatmentLaser *newTreatment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TreatmentLaser" inManagedObjectContext:SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext];
            newTreatment.date = [NSDate date];
            newTreatment.patient = _patient;

            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            break;
        }

        case 1:
        {
            TreatmentPASI *newTreatment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TreatmentPASI" inManagedObjectContext:SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext];
            newTreatment.date = [NSDate date];
            newTreatment.patient = _patient;

            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            TreatmentSurgery *newTreatment = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TreatmentSurgery" inManagedObjectContext:SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext];
            newTreatment.date = [NSDate date];
            newTreatment.patient = _patient;


            SurgerySites *surgerySite = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SurgerySites" inManagedObjectContext:SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext];
            surgerySite.treatmentSurgery = newTreatment;


            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
                return;
            }

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Method 2:

```
- (IBAction)onClickNewConsultation:(UIButton *)sender {

    Consult *newConsult = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Consult" inManagedObjectContext:SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext];
    newConsult.date = [NSDate date];
    newConsult.patient = _patient;

    ClinicalExam *clinicalExam = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClinicalExam" inManagedObjectContext:SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext];
    clinicalExam.consult = newConsult;


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![SCDataManager.app.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    //    [self update];


}
```

Delegate method (3):

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    if (_consultsFRC == controller) {
        if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {

            [_consultTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            [_consultTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toConsult" sender:self];
        }
        else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {

            //[_consultTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }

    }
    else if (_treatmentLasersFRC == controller) {
        if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {

            [_consultTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            [_consultTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:1] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTreatmentLaser" sender:self];
        }
        else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {

            //[_consultTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }
    else if (_treatmentPASIsFRC == controller) {
        if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {

            [_consultTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:2]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            [_consultTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:2] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTreatmentPASI" sender:self];
        }
        else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {

            //[_consultTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:2]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }
    else if (_treatmentProFormasFRC == controller) {
        if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert) {

            [_consultTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:3]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            [_consultTable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:3] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTreatmentProForma" sender:self];
        }
        else if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {

            [_consultTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:3]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }

    //    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toTreatmentLaser" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: Hard to say w/o seeing the FRCs, but is it that the delegate method is not called at all?  Or that the segue you expect doesn't happen?

Comment: The delegate method happens the first time this code is called, then when I pop back to the VC it doesn't anymore. The objects are saved to the database, but the delegate is never called when I click the button. It does however work for the treatment objects.